# why does set-default-font affect find-file-other-window?

Tags: emacs, fontconfig

I recently added the line

```
(set-default-font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1")
```

to my .emacs file.  After that `find-file-other-window` always opens a new window instead of utilizing existing windows.  Why would that happen!?  How can I fix it?

I don't understand how all this font-config magic works, so if it's actually obvious I'm sorry.

Edit: I have a pretty large resolution, and my font size has decreased pretty significantly.  Does `find-file-other-window` take into account available character space?  Perhaps it's deciding there's sooo much room it can afford to just open windows willy nilly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find-file-other-window` ultimately calls [`display-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html), which runs a complex algorithm to decide whether to reuse an existing window or make one and how. In particular, if `display-buffer` decides it needs to create or recycle a window, it tries calling [`split-window-preferred-function`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#index-split_002dwindow_002dpreferred_002dfunction-2094) to split the biggest window. By default, `split-window-preferred-function` is [`split-window-sensibly`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#index-split_002dwindow_002dsensibly-2095), which is willing to split windows vertically if they are more than [`split-height-threshold`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#index-split_002dheight_002dthreshold-2096) lines high, or failing that horizontally if they are more than [`split-width-threshold`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#index-split_002dwidth_002dthreshold-2097) columns wide.

It looks like you want

```
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
```

N.B. This answer applies to GNU Emacs 23. Earlier versions didn't have horizontal splitting. Later versions may do things differently.

---

A few ways to find this out (none straightforward):

- If you guess that what's going on is called splitting a window: `M-x apropos RET split RET` shows a number of variables and functions, and you might figure out which ones are relevant. Or if you guess that there's an option (there often is), `C-h v split- TAB` shows promising leads.
- The [documentation for `find-file-other-window`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Visiting-Functions.html#index-find_002dfile_002dother_002dwindow-1750) references [Displaying Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Buffers.html). (You have to go to the Elisp manual for this level of detail; within Emacs, `C-h i m elisp RET` brings up the Elisp manual, and `i find-file-other-window RET` leads you to the documentation for this function.) It's less clear that [`pop-to-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Buffers.html#index-pop_002dto_002dbuffer-2089) is the passage to read there; it references [Choosing Window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html) which contains the sought after information.
- `C-h f find-file-other-window RET` shows the built-in documentation for the function. It links to `display-buffer`. The description of `display-buffer` doesn't describe its operation in detail, so from there you need to either consult the Elisp manual as above or explore the source of `display-buffer` by clicking on `window.el`.

Comment: by God.  You're a genius and I love you.